How to open filter/search dialogue _inside_ breadcrumbs in VS Code?
I often use breadcrumbs to navigate larger source files. Until very recently, it was possible to hit CTRL + F to open a tiny search/filter box inside the breadcrumbs view. This is no longer possible with the most recent update of VS Code. CTRL + F now immediately jumps back into the search widget in the open editor.
From scanning through the shortcuts around breadcrumbs, I do not find anything that remotely sounds like "Filtering in breadcrumbs", only keyboard navigation with the arrow keys.
Was this feature silently removed from VS Code? Is there a new way to filter within the breadcrumbs?
Just FYI, I have the same problem with the terminal, where pressing CTRL + F does not open a search box, either.

Do you mean the bread crumbs bar, or the outline panel?

I mean the breadcrumbs bar, but I can't open a search/filter in the outline panel, either. I am less familiar with the outline, so I don't know whether it was ever there...

I never knew you could search in the breadcrumb bar, but if you try CTRL + ALT + F in the outline panel, you can search on breadcrumbs I think.

If you click on a breadcrumb item, it opens a list box.  From there Ctrl+Alt+F does open a Find Widget.  @TimothyG. You should post this as an answer before someone else does...

@Mark While that's an option, testing it out right now, its not very good... it seems to only find breadcrumbs within the current scope - I'm not sure if that's what the OP is looking for, but I don't know how the "original" way worked that seemingly is gone as the OP mentioned.  Also having to click into the breadcrumb bar first seems counterintuitive, but then again, that's probably necessary since CTRL + F normally would search within the active editor, or whatever has focus.

@TimothyG. I assume he is using the precise sequence I mentioned : "to open a tiny search/filter box inside the breadcrumbs view".  What else could "inside" mean here?

@TimothyG., Thanks. CTRL + ALT + F was exactly what I was looking for. This has been changed recently, but without me noticing. The shortcut is buried under "list.find" in the shortcuts list, so it is not easy to connect this to the breadcrumbs. Happy to accept this as an answer.

Bonus: Changing the keybinding of the "list.find" shortcut to CTRL + F restores the old behavior and makes searching the outline and the breadcrumbs more convenient.

By the way, if you want to return to using just Ctrl+F to open that Find Widget in the breadcrumbs dropdown list, just make this keybinding in your keybindings.json:
{
  "key": "ctrl+f",
  "command": "list.find",
  "when": "listFocus && listSupportsFind"

  // use this so ctrl+f woks for breadcrumbs but not Explorer
  //   "when": "listFocus && listSupportsFind && breadcrumbsActive",
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+f",
  "command": "-list.find",
  "when": "listFocus && listSupportsFind"
}

